# Wireless headphones can't use mic and audio at the same time

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, headphones

Whenever I connect my wireless earphones to my Ubuntu device, I am given 2 options in Output. Headset and handsfree. Handsfree sounds terrible, so I always use headset.
But if I want to use the built-in mic on the headphones, I must select Handsfree in the input section. This however changes the output to handsfree as well. Meaning I cannot use the microphone without having terrible audio quality.
How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a linux issue, it's a headset/hardware issue. The headphones aren't capable of sending the amount of data needed for both high-quality audio and microphone at the same time. You get to choose one. The same would apply to any operating system.

Answer (score 4):

Bluetooth headphones are limited in bandwidth, and can not send/receive enough data to handle both HD audio and microphone input at the same time. You get to choose between spending all the bandwidth on audio, and splitting it between lower-quality audio and mic input.

This is not an Ubuntu issue, any operating system would have this limitation, as it is inherent to the Bluetooth technology (and possibly the headphones' hardware).

Comment: But then why does it work perfectly fine on my phone?